# What is this sound effect called?

Tags: tuning, clarinet, accordion

In this video:

...from 1:13 to 1:20 there is a special sound connection between the clarinet and the accordion. I don't know how to describe it but sounds like a very nice transition (specially if you listening from the very beginning of the song).

**My Questions**

What is that 'in tune' sound effect called?
Is there any branch of music dedicated to the study of the dynamics of song through it? I mean, how do they know that at that particular time, that effect would sound nice(for me sounds like all the stuff they play before that moment, sound enhance that "in tune" effect).

Comment: The clarinet, accordion and voice (of accordion player) all play/sing a B. Not sure exactly what effect you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tuning issues aside, the effect you speak of is simply the clarinet staring the B note by himself on the downbeat and then the accordion playing an Amaj9 quietly on beat 4 with the same B on top and doing a crescendo while the clarinet holds his note. The effect is that the sounds of the two instruments merge into one. It doesn’t have a specific name,

Answer (score 3):

For me it sounds like the notes they are playing are not exactly in tune. They both play a B but the clarinet is slightly sharp.

This results in a so called beating: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beat_(acoustics)

Comment: Eek, yup, the accordion is flat as a *&^% right there. I'm not sure it's even close enough to beat, it just sounds 'out of tune'.

Comment: @Tetsujin I hate it when accordion players don’t tune before a performance! 